# Remote volume control on iPad?

Tags: ipad, remote-control

We have an iPad in office, which we use to play music when not being used for mobile app testing (etc.).

Is there a way to **remote control volume from desktop** (OS X)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup. http://download.cnet.com/Music-Remote-for-iPad-Remote-control-for-iPod-iPhone-and-iPad-Music/3000-2133_4-75177039.html.

Comment: Thank you, that looks interesting... Anything free? For OS X 10.5? :)

Comment: I don't think that you will be able to find anything else that doesn't require Jailbreaking... I know that you can jailbreak and then use VLC to control your iPad.